# Waiting for Debugger

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem. I created a new activity and I'm trying to link it
to the one I had before. I created an intent and the app does not give
me errors but on the phone I recive this message: `Waiting for Debugger: force close` and I have to close it.

***Any advice?***

At the intent I tried this too: `Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, MainActivity.class);` but then, I have this error:

`no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<MainActivity>) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)`

This is the code:

```
public class StartScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "StartScreen";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Starting.");

        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked startBtn.");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Logcat
>   05-25 21:52:18.345 23261-23261/? E/Zygote: v2
>   05-25 21:52:18.345 23261-23261/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10265
>       KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
>   05-25 21:52:18.347 23261-23261/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   05-25 21:52:18.347 23261-23261/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
>   05-25 21:52:18.350 23261-23261/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.mariacristina.quizzz 
>   05-25 21:52:18.356 23261-23261/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   05-25 21:52:18.399 23261-23261/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
>   05-25 21:52:18.659 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz-1/lib/arm
>   05-25 21:52:18.698 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   05-25 21:52:19.245 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   05-25 21:52:19.820 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>   05-25 21:52:19.823 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>   05-25 21:52:19.947 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>   05-25 21:52:19.949 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>   05-25 21:52:19.980 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
>   05-25 21:52:20.027 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/Choreographer: init sf_choreo_doframe   debug_Level : 0x4f4cdebug_game_running : false
>   05-25 21:52:20.157 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
>   05-25 21:52:20.170 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=71
>   05-25 21:52:20.173 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@a20c158[MainActivity] touchMode=true
>   05-25 21:52:20.209 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   05-25 21:52:20.240 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -256112640} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
>   05-25 21:52:20.241 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -256112640} hwInitialized=true
>   05-25 21:52:20.344 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
>   05-25 21:52:20.373 23261-23277/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
>   05-25 21:52:20.450 23261-23277/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   05-25 21:52:20.450 23261-23277/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   05-25 21:52:20.532 23261-23277/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
>   05-25 21:52:21.320 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz D/ViewRootImpl@577b63b[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
>   05-25 21:52:21.321 23261-23261/com.example.mariacristina.quizzz I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: try this maybe.  Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

Comment: remove usb cable then try, you are trying to attach debugger while running

Comment: @Deepakkaku I've already tried but it's the same

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I did it but my app still crash

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I post it up

Comment: You are doing something on your main which is taking a lot of time, thats why you end up in ANR state. i don't think the code you posted above is the problem, its in some other portion of the code

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I've found the problem. Thanks for the advice

Comment: happy to help!!